# hg remove all files listed in .hgignore

Tags: mercurial, ubuntu-13.10

I have a mercurial repo with `.hgignore` file. I want to remove all files from disk (`hg remove`) in this repo which match pattern(s) listed in `.hgignore`.

I can list all ignored files with `hg status -i` but I don't know how can I delete them.

.hgignore contents:

```
syntax: glob

build
\.egg*
*.pyc

.DS_Store
*.sublime-*
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can only run `hg remove` on files that are tracked. To remove tracked files that match the `.hgignore` patterns, run this command

```
$ hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"
```

This uses a [fileset](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#fileset) to select the right files.

If you want to remove files that are already ignored by Mercurial (not tracked), then see the [purge extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PurgeExtension). That can be used to cleanup a working copy so that it looks like a fresh checkout.

Answer (score 3):

From [`hgrc help`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias)

> A better example might be:
>
> `purge = !$HG status --no-status --unknown -0 | xargs -0 rm`
>
> which
>   will make hg purge delete all unknown files in the repository in the
>   same manner as the purge extension.

In order to delete ignored files instead of unknown you have ("hg help status") use `--ignored` | `-i` option instead of `--unknown`